# TypeError: 'torch.device' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch, typeerror, bert-language-model

I'm training a bert classifier on 5 class and I have many issues.
I'me using pytorch training loop for finetuning distillbert model on review classification a mong 5 classes. My model uses bert as first layer and I have added a linear classifier as outputs.

here is my train code:

```
    def train_step(model,
               dataloader_train:DataLoader,
               optimizer : torch.optim.Optimizer,
               loss_fn:torch.nn.functional = loss_fn,
               device = device):
    
    model.train()
    loss_train_total = 0     
    
    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, leave=False, disable=False)
    for batch in progress_bar:
        model.zero_grad()
          

        batch = {k: v.to(device) for k,v in batch.items()}
        outputs = model( input_ids = batch['input_ids'], 
                         attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
                       )
        print(batch['labels'])
        loss = loss_fn(
                       outputs.detach(),
                       batch['labels']
                      )
        loss_train_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train)
    progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})
    
    return loss_train_avg


def test_step(model,
              dataloader_test:DataLoader,
              optimizer : torch.optim.Optimizer,
              loss_fn:torch.nn.functional = loss_fn,
              device = device):

    model.eval()
    
    loss_val_total = 0
    predictions, true_vals = [], []
    
    for batch in dataloader_test:

        with torch.no_grad():
            
            outputs = model( input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device), 
                             attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
                           )
            
        loss = loss_fn(outputs,batch['labels'])
        logits = outputs
        loss_val_total += loss.item()

        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = batch['labels']
        predictions.append(logits)
        true_vals.append(label_ids)
    
    loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_test) 
    
    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
    true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals, axis=0)
            
    return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals





def train_loop(model,
            dataloader_train:DataLoader,
            dataloader_test:DataLoader,
            optimizer:torch.optim.Optimizer,
            epochs :int = epochs,
            device = device):
    
    results = {
                'train_loss' :[],
                'test_loss' : []
            }

    for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):
        loss_train_avg = train_step(  model,
                                      dataloader_train,
                                      optimizer,
                                      device)
        
        val_loss, predictions, true_vals = test_step( model,
                                                      dataloader_val,
                                                      optimizer,
                                                      device)
        results['train_loss'].append(loss_train_avg)
        results['test_loss'].append(val_loss)

        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'{output_dir}/{model_name}_epoch_{epoch}.model')

        tqdm.write(f'\nEpoch {epoch}')        
        val_f1 = F1_score(predictions, true_vals)
        tqdm.write(f'Train loss: {loss_train_avg}')
        tqdm.write(f'Test loss: {val_loss}')
        tqdm.write(f'F1 Score: {val_f1}')    
    
    return results, val_f1
    


model.to(device)

with mlflow.start_run(run_name='simple_bert'):

    mlflow.log_param('batch_size', batch_size)
    mlflow.log_param('learning_rate', lr)
    mlflow.log_param('num_epochs', epochs)

    results, f1_ = train_loop(model = model,
                    dataloader_train = dataloader_train,
                    dataloader_test = dataloader_test,
                    optimizer = optimizer,
                    device = device)
    
    f1_ = torch.tensor(f1_).float()
    mlflow.log_metric('f1 score',f1_)
    mlflow.end_run()
```

when running only this frist snippet, I have a typeerror : 'TypeError: 'torch.device' object is not callable'.

But there is no problem when I launch the following:

```
for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader_train):
    model.zero_grad()

    batch = {k: v.to(device) for k,v in batch.items()}
    outputs = model( input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device), 
                     attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
                   )
    print(batch['labels'])
    loss = loss_fn(
                   outputs.detach(),
                   batch['labels']
                  )
    print(loss)
    
    if i==0:
        break
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, when calling the loss fonction `loss = loss_fn(outputs.detach(), batch['labels'] )`